# EV SSL Custom green bar

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am interested in purchasing a SSL/TSL certificate for my website and I would like to know which retailer allows me to add my custom message in the green address bar like in this image: https://www.globessl.com/templates/2005/img/page/n/ev_brows.png

You can see there: "COMPANIA NATIONALA DE TRANSPORTURI AERIENE ..."

I want something like that too.

Answer (score 5):

You are speaking of Extended Validation Certificates. They are basically common X.509 SSL/TLS certificates, the only difference consist in a different (stricter) identification procedure needed to obtain them (compared to a "normal" certificate).

In order to issue a EVC, the Certification Authority requires the applying Company to provide some more documents and performs an "independent" audit on the real identity of the applicant.

The string displayed in the green bar by the majority of recent browsers is not a "custom message" but the name of the Company as verified by the CA.

Afaik, all major CAs (VerySign, Godaddy, Thawte, GeoTrust and so on) are able to issue EVC.

A technical note: an EVC is not cryptographically "more secure" of any other X.509 certificate in any way. It just provide a stronger assurance about the real identity of its owner.

Comment: I was interested in purchasing the Premium SSL from GoDaddy which also offers the Green Bar and encryption.
I am looking after green bar and encryption and would also like something to show that custom text.

Comment: As MariusPontmercy stated, it is not a custom message. It is the legally registered company name (or legally registered Trade Name).

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak from experience with Comodo, but you will not get an EV-SSL certificate approved unless your registered company name and address appears in the WHOIS details for the domain, and they may ask for headed paperwork from a solicitor or account confirming these details.
Also, one thing that many people slip up on is that the company name on the request form needs to be full and not contain *any* abbreviations (unless these abbreviations are also present in the registered company name).
You will not be able to get an EV-SSL (at least not from Comodo) with a custom company name, it has to match exactly. I have local copies of the simplified paperwork Comodo ask for if you want to know the data they ask for, but they aren't cheap.

Comment: I was interested in purchasing the Premium SSL from GoDaddy which also offers the Green Bar and encryption.
I am looking after green bar and encryption and would also like something to show that custom text.

Answer (score 0):

The company name is not something custom, it is actually the company name, which is verified by the SSL company, and you are required to provide documentation on the company when buying such an SSL certificate. Some browsers will not show the company name in full or at all and will require you to click the green bar and view more info on it.

Comment: How can I get that and where from ?